# SSH allows remote connections only after a local login to the server

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, login

I am new to linux and ssh. I set up ssh on my lubuntu 18.04.4.
I can log remotely in using user and password from my mac, but only after a successful local login. I am not using user and password login as I could not set up key login.

Help!
Thanks

Comment: During setup, did you choose to encrypt your home directory?

Comment: don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, networking issue:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cannot-login-via-ssh-before-performing-a-local-login/12103/3